# Wordpress Elementor "Form" : How to add radio input option with textfield

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor, wordpress-shortcode

I am using Wordpress with Elementor Pro..

I need to add a radio input option with textfield; the textfield is enabled automatically when the option is selected.

How to do that with elementor please?

Please see the picture.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hello, Anyone ?..

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript/jquery for your selection system.

1. define the selector on your elementor items.
2. write the function in your theme file js using your defined selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Script.
You must create a text field first. This script makes possible to show the text field when the 3rd radio button is clicked. When the 3rd button is clicked the text field is marked as "Requested" so the user must write something. Hope this helps you. (even though 2 years late response haha)

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Function to find the radio button and text field within the form
    function findElements() {
        // Find the radio button
        var radioBtn1 = document.querySelector('.elementor-field-type-radio input[id="ID OF YOUR FIRST BUTTON"]');
        var radioBtn2 = document.querySelector('.elementor-field-type-radio input[id="ID OF YOUR SECOND BUTTON"]');
        var radioBtn3 = document.querySelector('.elementor-field-type-radio input[id="ID OF YOUR THIRD BUTTON"]');
        // Find the text field
        var textField = document.querySelector('.elementor-field-type-text input[id="ID OF YOUR TEXT FIELD"]');
        
        return {radioBtn1: radioBtn1, radioBtn2: radioBtn2, radioBtn3: radioBtn3, textField: textField };
    }

    // Function to toggle visibility of text field based on radio button selection
    function toggleTextFieldVisibility() {
        var elements = findElements();

        if (elements.radioBtn3 && elements.textField) {
            // Hide the text field initially
            elements.textField.parentElement.style.display = 'none';

            // Uncheck all radio buttons initially
            elements.radioBtn1.checked = false;
            elements.radioBtn2.checked = false;
            elements.radioBtn3.checked = false;

            // Add event listener to the radio buttons
            elements.radioBtn1.addEventListener('change', function() {
                // Hide the text field if the radio button is checked
                elements.textField.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
                elements.textField.required = false; // Make the text field not required
            });

            elements.radioBtn2.addEventListener('change', function() {
                // Hide the text field if the radio button is checked
                elements.textField.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
                elements.textField.required = false; // Make the text field not required
            });
            
            elements.radioBtn3.addEventListener('change', function() {
                // Display the text field if the radio button is checked
                elements.textField.parentElement.style.display = 'block';
                elements.textField.required = true; // Make the text field required
            });
        } else {
            console.error('Could not find the radio button or text field.');
        }
    }

    // Call the function to initialize the script
    toggleTextFieldVisibility();
});
```